# Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens SQL

Tags: php, mysql, session, pdo

I'm making a web site and I need t send an information from the form using PHP and PDO.

PHP code:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO commentary (name,  surname,  email,  user_comment, user_id ) VALUES ( :name,  :surname,  :email,  :user_comment, '.$_SESSION['id'].') ';

$query_p = array(':name' => $_POST['name'],':surname' => $_POST['surname'], ':email' => $_POST['email'],':user_comment' => $_POST['email'], ':user_id'=>$_SESSION['id']); 

try 
{ 
    $statment = $dbh->prepare($query); 
    $result = $statment->execute($query_p); 
} 
catch(PDOException $e) 
{ 

    die("Can't run this query: " . $e->getMessage()); 
}
```

HTML code:

```
 <h1 class="contactHeader"> Form</h1>
<div class="form">
<form  id="contact" name="contact" method="post" action="user.php"  onreset="return confirm('Chcete to vymázat?')" method="post">

  <label class="leftElement"  for="name">Name </label><span class="required">*</span><br />
    <input class="leftElement" id="name" name="name" type="text" ><br />
  <label class="centerElement" for="surname">Surname:</label><span class="required">*</span><br />

   <input class="centerElement"  type="text" name="surname" id="surname"><br />
   <label class="leftElement"  for="email">Email: </label><span class="required">*</span><br />
   <input class="leftElement" type="text" name="email" id="email"><br />
    <label class="centerElement"   for="user_comment">Comment:</label><br />


     <textarea
     class="centerElement" id="user_comment" name="user_comment" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send">
    <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

In database in table "comentary" I have id,name,surname,email,user_comment and user_id which I get form session `$_SESSION['id']`. But when I try to send this form I get an error `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens,` 
May be I'm doing something wrong? Database connection is OK. I've already controled it.

Thank you.

Comment: The error message is self explanatory. You're trying to pass more values to `execute` than you have `:placeholders` in your query!

Comment: @deceze You mean the problem is in user_id?

Comment: Yes, you have no token `:user_id` in your query.

Comment: @deceze thank you too. I'm new in PHP :) So some times I do stupid mistakes. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO commentary (name,  surname,  email,  user_comment, user_id ) VALUES ( :name,  :surname,  :email,  :user_comment, '.$_SESSION['id'].') ';

$query_p = array(':name' => $_POST['name'],':surname' => $_POST['surname'], ':email' => $_POST['email'],':user_comment' => $_POST['email'], ':user_id'=>$_SESSION['id']);
```

You're not setting a :placeholder for your user_id so do not set one in your `execute`.

Comment: That did a thing. Thank you!

Comment: What is difference in your answer query and in question query ?

Comment: There is no difference, I posted the two lines to show what I am talking about.